# Java 8 optional No value present

Tags: java, spring, image, spring-boot, option-type

I have made this function and used optional although my image is not getting returned and is throwing an error NO VALUE PRESENT even though my db (MySQL) has data stored with the name

```java
@GetMapping(path = { "/get/{imageName}" })
public ImageModel getImage(@PathVariable("imageName") String imageName) throws IOException {
    final Optional<ImageModel> retrievedImage = imageRepository.findByName(imageName);
    ImageModel img = new ImageModel(retrievedImage.get().getName(), retrievedImage.get().getType(),
    decompressBytes(retrievedImage.get().getPic()));
    return img;
}
```

This is my dao class

```
public interface ImageRepository extends JpaRepository<ImageModel, Long> {
    Optional<ImageModel> findByName(String name);
    Optional<ImageModel> findById(Long id);
}
```

This is my model class where i have defined mysql database

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image_table")
public class ImageModel {
    public ImageModel() {
        super();
    }
    public ImageModel(String name, String type, byte[] pic) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.pic = pic;
    }
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    //image bytes can have large lengths so we specify a value
    //which is more than the default length for picByte column
    @Column(name = "pic", length = 1000)
    private byte[] pic;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public byte[] getPic() {
        return pic;
    }

    public void setPic(byte[] pic) {
        this.pic = pic;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging? Is `imageName` actually what you expect it to be? Are you sure such image exists in DB?

Comment: You should _almost never_ use `Optional#get`; the entire point is that you should be using constructs like `ifPresentOrElse` or `getOrElse`.

Comment: You should really never use [Optional#get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) without first checking if the value is present with [Optional#ifPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--). Or you can use [Optional#orElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) to set a default value if the _optional_ value is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The hint is in the name. An `Optional` object refers to something that doesn't necessarily have to be there. You need to tell the app what to do if an instance of `Optional` is not present:

```java
final Optional<ImageModel> retrievedImage = imageRepository.findByName(imageName);
return retrievedImage.get().orElse(null);
```

WRT your data query not returning what you're looking for, I would say that is a separate issue, and the code you have given doesn't detail that query of the database.

Comment: If I am doing `.orElse(null)` then I prefer not using Optional. Because it doesn't mean anything using it.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks Yeah I should have mentioned that. If you _always_ expect an object to be there then `Optional` is not necessary.

Comment: i get all this, but my main question is : even though I have the data in present then why it is not fetching the result

Answer (score 1):

The optional pattern ( also monad) lets you control the flow if data is present or not, which helps you avoid null pointer exceptions ( the billion dollar mistake)

You can take advandage of the optional pattern by either using:

1. `optional.ifPresent(e-> decompress(e))`
2. `optional.orElseGet`( return a new Image) if this is the use case.
3. `optional.orElseThrow(...)` for example if you want to throw an exception if there's no
   image present in the database and stop the flow in this way.
4. use `optional.isPresent()` in an if condition to hanadle the the case in which the image is null.

And control your flow more precisely and

Comment: i get all this, but my main question is : even though I have the data in present then why it is not fetching the result

Comment: do you mean why the repo isn't returning data ?

Comment: yes , I have update the this post with all the info. Why i am not able to fetch data